# Grid plugin / script - name escapes me

Tags: after-effects, plugins, script

I used to have a great free plugin or script for automatically laying objects out on a specified grid in After Effects... For example, I want to place 18 squares on a 3 x 6 grid of a specified size.  (I don't want to use Trapcode Form for this- I need each object as a separate layer in my comp).

Can anyone remind me?  I've tried googling for it, but no luck so far...

Comment: Would it have been [Trapcode's Echospace](http://www.redgiant.com/products/trapcode-echospace/)?

Comment: No, it was a small pane that let you choose grid sizes, and then snapped a load of shapes to specific positions

Comment: Maybe gridder? http://aescripts.com/gridder/

Comment: Yes - totally was!  Thanks!  Please convert into an answer, and I'll mark as correct!  They need better keyword searching on aescripts - I did look!